# How to convert regular for loop to java 8 streams

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have classes `Product` and `RegionAllocation`

```
class Product{

int id;
String region;
int price;

Product(int I'd, int price,String region){
this.id = id;
this.price = price;
this.region = region;
}
 //getters for id and price
}

List<Product> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(1, 30, "LDN")
list.add(2, 25, "NYK")
```

And

```
class RegionAllocation{
int price;
int alloQty;

RegionAllocation(Product p)
this.price = p.getPrice();
}

RegionAllocation allocate(int a){
this.alloQty+=a;
return this;
}
```

}

I want to write a function using streams, which streams through products and for each product creates RegionAllocation object and sets allocate function based on values of price

```
List<RegionAllocation> reg = new ArrayList();
for(Product p : products) {
    RegionAllocation r = new RegionAllocation(p); 

    if(p.getRegion().equals("LDN") {
        r.allocate(0);
    } else{          
        r.allocate(p.getPrice()*5)
    }
    reg.add(r);
    }

return reg;
```

I want to write above using java 8 stream.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: If you want to learn streams, take each element and see what it does. Then combine them two at a time. Eventually, you'll be the one answering questions like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting regular loops to `Stream`s it is a good idea to first determine what each piece of code does.

If we take a look at your for loop we can deduce the following functionality:

```java
// Creation of an empty list
List<RegionAllocation> reg = new ArrayList();
// Loop over the products
for(Product p : products) {
    // Create a new RegionAllocation
    RegionAllocation r = new RegionAllocation(p); 

    // Allocate the RegionAllocation
    if(p.getRegion().equals("LDN") {
        r.allocate(0);
    } else{          
        r.allocate(p.getPrice()*5)
    }
    // Add the RegionAllocation to the list
    reg.add(r);
}

return reg;
```

From this we can already see that the code inside your for loop consists of two distinct parts; the creation and allocation of a new `RegionAllocation` from a `Product` and adding this new `RegionAllocation` to the list.

The first step in this case would be to extract the creation and allocation of `RegionAllocation` to a separate method like so (I have wrapped your original code in a method and called it `createRegionAllocations`)

```java
public List<RegionAllocation> createRegionAllocations(List<Product> products) {
    List<RegionAllocation> reg = new ArrayList();
    for(Product p : products) {
        RegionAllocation r = createRegionAllocation(p);
        reg.add(r);
    }

    return reg;
}

private RegionAllocation createRegionAllocation(Product p) {
    RegionAllocation r = new RegionAllocation(p); 

    if(p.getRegion().equals("LDN") {
        r.allocate(0);
    } else{          
        r.allocate(p.getPrice()*5)
    }

    return r;
}
```

Now we can convert the loop to a stream. The 'for' part of the loop

```java
for (Product p : products)
```

becomes

```java
products.stream() // Stream<Product>
```

which is a `Stream<Product>` aka, a stream of products.

The method `createRegionAllocation` creates a `RegionAllocation` from a `Product` so it transforms one type (`Product`) into another type (`RegionAllocation`). This is what the `map` method does for streams. Its signature is

```java
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper)
```

where `T` is the type of the stream `map` is called on and `R` is the new type. So in your case we can now do

```java
products.stream() // Stream<Product>
    .map(p -> createRegionAllocation(p)) // Stream<RegionAllocation>
```

The final step is now to create a list of the stream. This is where the `collect` method is for. There are a whole lot of ways to collect a stream but for this case when we collect we do

```java
products.stream() // Stream<Product>
    .map(p -> createRegionAllocation(p)) // Stream<RegionAllocation>
    .collect(Collectors.toList()) // List<RegionAllocation>
```

Besides `Collectors.toList()` (which collects to a `List`) you can also do for example `Collectors.toSet()` (which collects to a `Set`) or a whole bunch of other custom collectors if you need them. But for `List`s you only need to remember the `.collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Finally we can use method reference for the `createRegionAllocation`:

```java
products.stream() // Stream<Product>
    .map(this::createRegionAllocation) // Stream<RegionAllocation>
    .collect(Collectors.toList()) // List<RegionAllocation>
```

So when we put it all together we get

```java
public List<RegionAllocation> createRegionAllocations(List<Product> products) {
    return products.stream()
        .map(this::createRegionAllocation)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private RegionAllocation createRegionAllocation(Product p) {
    RegionAllocation r = new RegionAllocation(p); 

    if(p.getRegion().equals("LDN") {
        r.allocate(0);
    } else{          
        r.allocate(p.getPrice()*5)
    }

    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` and collect the stream to the list:

```
List<RegionAllocation> reg = products.stream()
    .map(p -> new RegionAllocation(p).allocate(p.getRegion().equals("LDN") ? 0 : p.getPrice() * 5))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```